# NHibernate conversation with ASP.NET+IoC+PostSharp?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, inversion-of-control, aop

Does anybody know a good example of how an NHibernate conversation can be used in a Web context (ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC) using an IoC container and AOP? Personally, I use Castle/Windsor and PostSharp, but I will appreciate everything that points me to the right direction.

Comment: And you want to use IoC and AOP to do...?

Comment: Yes, that was my question. So why do you ask...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fabio Maulo](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/) has talked about this [in some blog posts](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/01/aspect-conversation-per.html), and I think there is some relevant code in the [uNhAddins project](http://groups.google.com/group/unhaddins).  [Dario Quintana](http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/) has [a downloadable example](http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2007/11/17/3-layer-example-of-nhibernate-springnet-aop/).  Furthermore, there is [an AOP category](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/tags/AOP/default.aspx) on the [NHibernate community site](http://nhforge.org/).

HTH!